# Is there way to import color scheme from PHPStorm to Sublime Text?

Tags: import, export, phpstorm, sublimetext, color-scheme

I have made good color scheme in PHPStorm for CSS, JS, HTML, PHP, etc. It has very good visual editor. But how can I export it from Jetbrains IDE and import to Sublime?

I tried to do it with services like [this](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com). but it's not the same.

Comment: You can definitely export your scheme from PhpStorm: File | Export Settings (it will be a jar file). But I don't know about Sublime, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, i know it. I have my .icls, i see that it has XML structure, but after that i don't know what to do...

Comment: I don't think that Sublime can import PHPStorm color scheme

Comment: Ask at https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/new?template=enhancement_or_feature_request.md